# Threedimensional bwdist function for octave

Tags: image, octave

The [Image Package](http://wiki.octave.org/Image_package) from octave offers a `bwdist` function which is different to Matlab's `bwdist`([Link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwdist.html)) as it works only on twodimensional matrices and not on 3dimensional ones.

Is there a similar function to Matlabs `bwdist` function that can also handle threedimensional matrices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, just write one yourself, e.g.

```
function Out = bwdist3D (Obj)
  Obj        = logical (Obj);
  ObjSize    = size (Obj);
  ObjIndices = find (Obj == true);
  [X, Y, Z] = ndgrid (1 : ObjSize(1), 1 : ObjSize(2), 1 : ObjSize(3)); 

  Out = zeros ([ObjSize, length(ObjIndices)]);
  for Iter = 1 : length (ObjIndices)
    [x, y, z] = ind2sub (ObjSize, ObjIndices(Iter));
    Out(:, :, :, Iter) = sqrt ((X - x).^2 + (Y - y).^2 + (Z - z).^2 );      
  end  

  Out = min (Out, [], 4);
end
```

The only downside is that it won't be as optimised, but it should do the trick.
<sub>PS: Note this is for guidance only; clearly the above function is lacking all the necessary input checks / sanitisation any proper function should have.</sub>

---

**EDIT: fully vectorised version of the above**

```
function Out = bwdist3D (Obj)
  [X, Y, Z] = ndgrid (1 : size (Obj, 1), 1 : size (Obj, 2), 1 : size (Obj, 3)); 
  [x, y, z] = ind2sub (size(Obj), reshape(find(Obj>0), [1,1,1,sum(Obj(:)>0)]));
  Out = min (sqrt((X-x).^2 + (Y-y).^2 + (Z-z).^2), [] ,4);
end
```

<sub>PS: code-golf at its finest :p</sub>